# AT24C04 EEPROM Byte write

Tags: embedded, stm32, eeprom

I am using AT24C04 or AT24C16 using STM32 MCU with STM32CubeIDE for data storage. I am trying to write an address 256, but in both the IC the data gets collapsed or unable to write properly.

For the better understanding I have attached the debugging image:
[image]

What is the solution?

Comment: Copy your code as TEXT into your question. Btw. What do you expect when using I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT how long your memory address could be?

Comment: As I see in datasheet this Atmel EEPROM use 8 byte internal data address, so why you use MEMADD_SIZE_16BIT for read and MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT for write? address 256 needs more than 8 bits, so you should use 16 bit address size?

Comment: While the debugger view may be useful, you should explain what it shows and how that differs from what you expected.  And do not post _pictures of text_, to provide a solution based on your existing code or to try your solution requires typing all that code in again or OCR'ing it) rather than simply copy and pasting it.

Comment: @DraženGrašovec re. _" address 256 needs more than 8 bits, so you should use 16 bit address size?"_, the _word address byte_ is 8 bit, so no, you should certainly not use a 16 bit address.  The upper bits of the data word address are conveyed in the _device address_ byte.  You are right however that using an 8-bit address for write and 16 for read makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AT24C04 device has 512 * 8 bits, requiring a 9-bit data word address, but the *address word* is only 8-bit.  The most significant bit of the address is conveyed in the bit 1 of the *Device Address Byte*. Effectively the device is addressed as if it were two separate 256 x 8 bit EEPROMs with addresses `0xA0` and `0xA2` (assuming A1 and A2 pins are tied low), as indicated in the [*datasheet*](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/doc5226.pdf)

[image: ![enter image description here]

So to write to data word address offset 256 (byte zero of the upper page) for example:

```c
HAL_I2C_Mem_Write( &hi2c2, EEPROM_WRITE_ADDRESS | A8_BIT, 0,
                   I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, datawd, 6, 100 );
```

Where `A8_BIT` has value `0x02u`.

Similarly to write to address 256:

```c
HAL_I2C_ Mem Read( &hi2c2, EEPROM_READ_ADDRESS | A8_BIT, 0,
                   I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, datar2, 6, 100 ) ;
```

No substitute for actually reading and understanding the datasheet.  You would do well to wrap all this into an EEPROM read/write interface will deal with all this transparently given a 9-bit address and deal with writes spanning the page boundary by issuing two separate writes.

AT24C16 is similar but has an 11-bit data word address, with the *three* most-significant address bits (page address 0 to 7) in the device address byte:
[image]
So in this case the device addresses for each page are:

- `EEPROM_READ_ADDRESS | (page_address << 1)`
- `EEPROM_WRITE_ADDRESS | (page_address << 1)`

Where page address is 0 to 7 and can be determined from the data word address by:

- `page_address = (data_word_address & 0x70u) >> 8u`

The AT24C16 does not have external I<sup>2</sup>C address pins.

The same expressions can be used for AT24C04 of course, only `page_address` would be 0 or 1, with a `data_word_address` mask of `0x10`.  Though the mask is not critical if all `data_word_address` values are in range for the specific EEPROM - making it easier to write one driver for both EEPROMs (and AT24C08).

There are other caveats with both devices that you need to be aware of such as you cannot cannot write more than 16 bytes consecutively in a single I<sup>2</sup>C transaction, and cannot write consecutive bytes spanning a 256 byte page boundary.  All compelling reasons for writing an EEPROM agnostic API rather than direct I2C HAL access, to make all that transparent.

---

To explain the debugger output, I suspect that the invalid address 256 (0x100) becomes an 8-bit address 0x01 (the most significant byte is interpreted as the 8-bit address), so you are reading the page 0 data, starting from the second byte.

The reason why the read from data word 16 is offset I am less certain about, but in both cases using a 16-bit data word address when the device only accepts 8-bits is not going to help - it does not really need any explanation since it is clearly an invalid transaction for this device, so you would not expect correct results.

Comment: @MATHEWA : You are welcome, but I would bring your attention to the commenting guidelines at https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment with respect to the _When shouldn't I comment?_ part.

Comment: @MATHEWA : You are welcome, but you might take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment (the _When shouldn't I comment?_ part) - SO has a system of answer acceptance and up-voting.  Feel free to try the solution before doing that  (or not), no update required.  You might also address the comments against the question by editing the question before it attracts enough _close_ votes to get closed. I.e. at least post the code as text in code mark-up.